# Nikto authentication

Tags: web-application, web-scanners, nikto

I am trying to complete a war game on Hell Bound Hackers.

I wish to use the nikto scanner to check some pages for vulnerabilities, however I first need to log into the Hell Bound Hackers war game, and then begin scanning Pen Test 1 challenge.

Here is the URL on the specific challenge:

> https://www.hellboundhackers.org/challenges/pentest/pentest1/index.php

The command I am trying to use is this, however the scanner keeps on getting redirected to the index page `https://www.hellboundhackers.org` which is frustrating as I wish to scan `/challenge/pentest/pentest1/index.php`. I believe this is because the authentication `-id+` part is not working correctly.

```
nikto -ssl -id username:password -h https://www.hellboundhackers.org/challenges/pentest/pentest1/index.php?
```

I believe I need to log in with my web browser, and then somehow copy the cookie to nikto?

Comment: Have you run a packet capture and see why you are getting redirected? Why are you set on running Nikto? Have you used the `-Display` parameter to debug?

Comment: @schroeder If I go to that URL without logging in I get redirected to the homepage, so obviously I need to login to do the challenge.

Comment: But do you know *why*? Is there a redirect, error, message, etc.? If it is a wargame, especially, there is no such thing as "obviously",

Comment: @schroeder Dude just visit that challenge URL in a web browser, you get redirected to the homepage as it wants you to login I believe? You have to be a member of HellBoundHackers to do challenges.

Comment: Dude, this is your question and your problem. Just fire up Wireshark (or Burp) and see for yourself. You don't need to be a member... If you want to do war games and if you want to be a security auditor, then you will have to start digging down through the technology layers to start understanding *why* things happen.

Comment: There has been a misunderstanding. The answer you provided will probably work, thank you.

Comment: If you try to visit that Pen Test 1 challenge without logging in it says "You need to be logged in for this challenge!" but does not redirect you. Anyway, the answer you provided will most likely work.

Comment: It's not my answer. If it does work, please mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

I actually went ahead and checked out your challenge and noticed that it required the cookie `fusion_user` for loading up the challenge. This can be confirmed from the BurpSuite Screenshot I have posted below:

[image: Burp Suite Repeater showing the fusion_user Cookie in Action]

Hence when scanning using nikto we will have to send across this cookie along with the requests.

There are two ways that I know of to do this.

### **Method 1**

1. Open the nikto.conf file in the location `/etc/nikto.conf`
2. Search for the text STATIC-COOKIE and add your cookie and its value like the image below.

[image: Adding the Cookie Value]

3. Now that we have added the cookie you might want to proxy it through burpsuite to verify the traffic that nikto generates. To do so set the proxy in the nikto.conf file as depicted in the image below.

[image: Setting the proxy]

4. Try running nikto now using the below command

   nikto --host https://www.hellboundhackers.org/challenges/pentest/pentest1/index.php -useproxy
5. **[Possible Errors]** In case you get the below error proceed to step 6

> - ERROR: Proxy error: opening stream: can't connect: proxy connect failed: proxy connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed: Invalid argument at
>     /var/lib/nikto/plugins/LW2.pm line 5157.

6. The above error could probably be caused by an SSL Error in Nikto itself. The temporary workaround would be to `LW_SSL_ENGINE` from `auto` to `SSLeay` as depicted in the image below.

[image: Changing the SSL Engine]

Now that you have done all that is required try running the command

```
nikto --host https://www.hellboundhackers.org/challenges/pentest/pentest1/index.php -useproxy
```

once again and observe the traffic in BurpSuite, Nikto should now ideally be scanning the Application with your added cookie.

### **Method 2**

The second method is for you to try around. You could set the user-agent in nikto, proxy it through burp and replace the user-agent with the cookie value using the Match and Replace feature of burp.

Do let me know if you find any issues while implementing the above fixes.

Comment: is there any way we can set cookie in nikto 's command line without embedded in local file ?

Answer (score 3):

If someone wants to directly set a cookie in nikto's command line without changing  `nikto.conf` file, try:

```
nikto -h <IP or hostname> -O STATIC-COOKIE="name=value"
```